# dispatching an action returns undefined in callback

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component, I have :

```
getCatalogItems(id = 12, sessionId = "anythingForNow", filterBy = []) {
    return this.props.actions.getCatalogInfo(id, sessionId, filterBy)
      .then(catalogItemsReturned=> {
        console.log("CATALOG ITEMS RETURED", catalogItemsReturned) //always undefined
      })
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("component will mount called")
    this.getCatalogItems();
  }
```

`render` function of this component gets called like 5-6 times for some reason even when I am not changing any state at all.

2. I pass result from the action to this component as a prop ( I am using redux) through map state to props and the result from this triggered actions becomes available in render function when it calls itself for 3rd or 4th time.

What is the reason? How could I fix it?

My triggered action is getting the result through API call, but for some reason, I am not getting it in `then` part of dispatch action in `getCatalogItems` function

This is what my action looks like: Anything wrong with this?

```
export function getCatalogItemsSuccess(catalogItems) {
  return {
    type: types.LOAD_CATALOG_SUCCESS,
    catalogItems   //courses:courses
  }
}


export function getCatalogInfo(id = 12, sessionId="anythingForNow", filterBy = []){ 
      return function (dispatch) {
    return catalogProductsAPI.getProductsByCategoryId(id, sessionId, filterBy)
      .then(
      catalogItems =>{
        console.log("catalog INFO in actinnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", catalogItems) // I get the right results here
        dispatch(getCatalogItemsSuccess(catalogItems));
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log("errorin get catalog", err);
      throw(err);
    }); //the function from API would return a promise

  };
}
```

Comment: The second `console.log` gets `undefined` because the `.then` callback in `getCatalogItems` implicitly returns `undefined`. I can only assume that you are also not properly resolving the promise in `this.props.actions.getCatalogInfo`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Check please

Comment: Just as I expected. The function you pass to `.then` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @FelixKling: Hm? Where ? returning here : return function (dispatch) {
    return catalogProductsAPI.getProductsByCategoryId(id, sessionId, filterBy) is not sufficient? Where else do I need to return from?

Comment: @FelixKling:Please check the updae